# Second async function never finishes

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Here is a simplified version of some code I am writing for an electron app. I need two function to run, one after the other. Each needs to make an API call, and then wait for the response before finishing.

```
async function build_page()
{
    await func_1()
    await func_2()
}

async function func_1()
{
    console.log("1 Start")

    await send().then(
        function (response)
        {
            console.log("1 Middle")
        }
    )
    console.log("1 End")
}

async function func_2()
{
    console.log("2 Start")

    await send().then(
        function (response)
        {
            console.log("2 Middle")
        }
    )
    console.log("2 End")
}

function send()
{

    const request = require("request-promise-native")

    return request({
        url: "http://localhost:7296/Categories",
        method: "POST",
        json: true,
        body: {"token": localStorage.getItem("token")}
    })

}
```

I want the console to print "1 Start, 1 Middle, 1 End, 2 Start, 2 Middle, 2 End", but currently, it only makes it to "2 Start". I am unsure why func_2 is not finishing. When I comment out the call to func_1, func_2 finishes as expected, and when I swap the calls to func_1 and func_2, then func_1 only makes it to "1 Start".

Comment: Is this in node.js by itself?

Comment: It is in Electron, which uses Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must of been something related to the request-promise-native library, because I was able to fix the issue by porting it to use the fetch library instead.

I replaced the body of the send function with the following code:

```
return fetch(
    "http://localhost:7296/".concat(endpoint),
    {
        method: method,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(input)
    }
).then(response => response.json())
```